# Regex to find specific character between two other characters

Tags: regex, notepad++

I've been trying to find a way to find a single comma between inverted commas without much luck. Example: "text , text " - how do I isolate the "," between the inverted commas line by line in a flat file?

My attempt .["].[,].["].

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, in NPP, perhaps, `("[^"]*),([^"]*")` is the best approach, however, it means you will need several "Replace All" presses. Are you trying to remove it? Then replace with `$1$2`.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to match? Can you give examples of what should and shouldn't match? What should be matched in those examples?

Comment: The solution I am looking for should only select the comma between the inverted commas - I do not think I can be more clear

Answer (score 1):

this regex will work

(?<=truck).*(?=car)

finds e.g. "plane" in the string
truckplanecar

so for test,test the regex would be 
(?<=test).*(?=test)

PS. can you please provide an more detailed example what you would like to do

Comment: Another example could include: aaa "test abc xyz " ccc how do I only select abc between the inverted commas?

Comment: it's a bit tricky, but if the string always has the exact same 'style'
(?<=test )\w*(?=\ )        don't remove the space before the last ')'

PS. you can use https://regex101.com/ to test your regex

Answer (score 0):

Try using 2 group at the start and end of the string, the following regex should work:

```
(".*),(.*")
```

it does match the example you've shared:

> "text , text "

Furthermore, using groups, you can isolate the string before the comma and afterwards, in case you'll be needed it.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work - tried it in RegExr online and it selects everything between the inverted commas. I need the expression to only select the single comma between the inverted commas

Comment: If you want to capture the comma alone, then use ' ".*(,).*" '
the signs "(" and ")" will help you get only the expression you wanted.

Further a do, I recommend to use RegexBuddy, it's a free-software that help you analysis and write regexs. You even able to test and debug the regex.